JavaFX TreeTableView, Selection Bar with default color after losing focus
When customizing the cell inside the TreeTableView and then selecting any row, the color of the bar is in the default modena style, up to this point it is correct.
After losing focus the text of the selection bar is not in the default with black color
How to solve this in JavaFX, is there an elegant solution?
I tried
tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::focusedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill());

but it also does not work correctly when losing focus

as expected

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableView; 
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SelectionBarColorFocus extends Application {

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         TreeTableView<Person> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();

        // Criar colunas
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());
         
        
        nameColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, String> param) -> {

            TreeTableCell<Person, String> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, String>() {
        
                   final ImageView imv = new ImageView();
                   final Text text = new Text("");
                   
                   HBox hbox = new HBox(imv, text);
                    
                   {
                      tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::selectedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill());                       
                      // tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::focusedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill());                       
                   }
                  
                    
                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            text.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
                            text.setText(item);
                            setGraphic(hbox);
                            
                        }else {                            
                            text.setText("");
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    private void updateTextFill() {
                         text.setFill(getTableRow().isSelected() ? Color.WHITE: Color.ORANGE);
                    }   
                };

                return cell;
            }
        );

        
        
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> addressColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Address");
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().addressProperty());



        
        TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().ageProperty());
        
        ageColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> param) -> {
            TreeTableCell<Person, Number> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, Number>() {
                
                boolean flat = false;
                final Text text = new Text("");
                
                {
                  focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                          System.out.println("jorge focused="+isNowFocused);
                      }
                  );   
                }
                
                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    
                    if(flat == false) {                         
                        tableRowProperty().flatMap(TreeTableRow::selectedProperty).addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> updateTextFill(item, empty));                        
                        flat = true;
                    }                    
                    updateTextFill(item, empty);
                }
                
            
                private void updateTextFill(Number item, boolean empty) {                    
                    if(item != null && item.intValue() != -1) {
                            text.setFill(Color.BLUE);                          
                            text.setText(item.toString());
                            setGraphic(text);
                        
                    }else {
                        text.setText("");
                        setText("");
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                    text.setFill(getTableRow().isSelected() ? Color.WHITE: Color.BLUE);
                }    
                
            };
            
            return cell;
         });
        
        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        addressColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        ageColumn.setPrefWidth(100);
    
        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, addressColumn, ageColumn);

        TreeItem<Person> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Persons", "", -1));
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Alice", "456 Park Ave", 25)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Bob", "789 Broadway", 35)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Carol", "987 Elm St", 40)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("John", "123 Main St", 40))
        );

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);
        
        
        Button b = new Button("Row Lost Focus");
        
        StackPane st = new StackPane();
        st.getChildren().add(b);
        
        bp.setCenter(treeTableView);
        bp.setBottom(st);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 300);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TreeTableView SelectionBar Lost Focus");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    
    
    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty name;
        private StringProperty address;
        private IntegerProperty age;

        public Person(String name, String address, int age) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty addressProperty() {
            return address;
        }

        public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}


Do you need to use a Text in the cells? Why not just set the cell's text directly and set the graphic to the ImageView? That way you can manage the colors with CSS.

Also, what is the desired outcome here? Your code explicitly sets the text fill in the name column to either white or orange depending on whether the row is selected or not, which seems to be what you observe. When are you expecting it to be the default?

This is just an example of using setGraphic, that's where the problem lies. This is just to illustrate the issue. What is expected is that when you lose focus, the text on the bar will turn black, as shown in the image above. To do this, simply run the program, select any line and then click on the button to lose focus.

The problem arises because you explicitly set the text fill to either white or orange, so of course it will never be the default dark grey color. What I am trying to establish (and you keep failing to explain) is whether or not a solution that uses the cell's text and CSS (instead of creating your own text object, for absolutely no apparent reason) will suffice.

Forget the Text object, that's not the point

So you want, for the name column: orange if not selected, white if selected and focused, dark grey if selected and not focused?

Please, to understand what I want, just run the program, select a line and then click on the button. You will see that when the bar loses focus the letter turns white, I need it to turn black, as in the image above, and it needs to be using setGraphic(...) because of the customizations of other similar cases.

I have run the program, and I have seen what it does, which is exactly what you wrote the code for it to do. You keep saying "I need it to turn black" but in the image it is grey, not black. If you don't want the text to be white, why did you write the code for it to turn white? Can you please explain your requirements in terms of what color you want the text to be under the combinations of selected and focused?

ok, I want it to have the color of the post image when the bar loses focus

So, again, is this the requirement? The text color should be orange when the row is not selected, white when it is selected and focused, and grey when it is selected and not focused? Yes or no? If "no", what is the correct requirement?

The correct result is the default color of the Modena selection bar.
It doesn't matter if the cell is orange or another color, I want it to have the default color after selecting any row and when losing focus the bar also has the default color.

So you want your custom colors (orange/blue) only when it is not selected?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The default colors in cells (and other controls) are defined in the modena CSS file, whose source code you can see here. For cells, the text fill has the following definition:
    -fx-text-background-color: ladder(
        -fx-background,
        -fx-light-text-color 45%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  46%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  59%,
        -fx-mid-text-color   60%
    );

where the individual colors are defined as
    -fx-dark-text-color: black;
    -fx-mid-text-color: #333;
    -fx-light-text-color: white;

Then this is applied to text in various controls, in this case with
.tree-table-row-cell {
    /* Other CSS properties omitted */
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}

This means that if the text is drawn over something for which fx-background is dark (less than 45% intensity), the text will be white (-fx-light-text-color); if there is a "medium" background (between 46% and 59%) the text will be black (-fx-dark-text-color), and over a light background (above 60% intensity) it will be a dark grey (-fx-mid-text-color: #333;).
By default, the background is a very light grey, so the text appears dark grey. When the row is selected and focused, the background is the accent color, which is less than 45% intensity, so the text automatically changes to white. When the row is selected but not focussed, the background is a light grey (not as light as the unselected background) and the text becomes dark grey (the "mid text color") again.
The recommended approach for modifying styles is to provide your own style sheet. Since you are using text objects, these are not by default styled, so you need to give them a style class (or id, but since there will be multiple text object in the same column, I recommend using a CSS class).
From what I understand of your requirements, you want the text to be orange for the name column and blue for the age column, but only when the row is not selected. When the row is selected, you want the default colors (whether those are default for selected+focused or selected+unfocused).
You can achieve this with the following:
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SelectionBarColorFocus extends Application {

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeTableView<Person> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>();

        // Criar colunas
        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().nameProperty());


        nameColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, String> param) -> {

                    TreeTableCell<Person, String> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, String>() {

                        final ImageView imv = new ImageView();
                        final Text text = new Text("");

                        HBox hbox = new HBox(imv, text);

                        {
                            text.getStyleClass().add("name-cell-text");
                        }


                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {

                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                text.setText(item);
                                setGraphic(hbox);

                            }else {
                                text.setText("");
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }
                        }

                    };

                    return cell;
                }
        );



        TreeTableColumn<Person, String> addressColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Address");
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().addressProperty());




        TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> ageColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Age");
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getValue().ageProperty());

        ageColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> param) -> {
            TreeTableCell<Person, Number> cell = new TreeTableCell<Person, Number>() {

                final Text text = new Text("");

                {
                    text.getStyleClass().add("age-cell-text");
                }

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null && item.intValue() != -1) {
                        text.setText(item.toString());
                        setGraphic(text);
                    } else {
                        setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }

            };

            return cell;
        });

        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
        addressColumn.setPrefWidth(200);
        ageColumn.setPrefWidth(100);

        treeTableView.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, addressColumn, ageColumn);

        TreeItem<Person> rootItem = new TreeItem<>(new Person("Persons", "", -1));
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Alice", "456 Park Ave", 25)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Bob", "789 Broadway", 35)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("Carol", "987 Elm St", 40)),
                new TreeItem<>(new Person("John", "123 Main St", 40))
        );

        rootItem.setExpanded(true);
        treeTableView.setRoot(rootItem);


        Button b = new Button("Row Lost Focus");

        StackPane st = new StackPane();
        st.getChildren().add(b);

        bp.setCenter(treeTableView);
        bp.setBottom(st);

        Scene scene = new Scene(bp, 500, 300);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX TreeTableView SelectionBar Lost Focus");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



    public static class Person {
        private StringProperty name;
        private StringProperty address;
        private IntegerProperty age;

        public Person(String name, String address, int age) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.address = new SimpleStringProperty(address);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public StringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public StringProperty addressProperty() {
            return address;
        }

        public IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return age;
        }
    }
}

and the stylesheet
.tree-table-row-cell .name-cell-text {
    -fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
    -fx-text-background-color: orange;
}

.tree-table-row-cell .age-cell-text {
    -fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
    -fx-text-background-color: blue;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected .name-cell-text, .tree-table-row-cell:selected .age-cell-text {
    /* restore default */
    -fx-text-background-color: ladder(
        -fx-background,
        -fx-light-text-color 45%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  46%,
        -fx-dark-text-color  59%,
        -fx-mid-text-color   60%
    );
}

This works by explicitly setting the -fx-text-background-color to orange or blue, and then by restoring the default ladder in a selected row. Other solutions are possible here: for example
.tree-table-row-cell .name-cell-text {
    -fx-fill: orange;
}

.tree-table-row-cell .age-cell-text {
    -fx-fill: blue;
}

.tree-table-row-cell:selected .name-cell-text, .tree-table-row-cell:selected .age-cell-text {
    /* restore default */
    -fx-fill: -fx-text-background-color;
}

Note there are no listeners and the cell implementations are very basic.
This can be simplified by using just the text property of the cell instead of explicit text objects. It is unclear if you need those for your real application for some unspecified reason, but here is how I would implement the cells in this specific example:
        nameColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, String> _) -> {

                    TreeTableCell<Person, String> cell = new TreeTableCell<>() {
                        final ImageView imv = new ImageView();
                        @Override
                        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);
                            if (item != null) {
                                setText(item);
                                setGraphic(imv);
                            } else {
                                setText("");
                                setGraphic(null);
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    cell.getStyleClass().add("name-cell");
                    return cell;
                }
        );

and
        ageColumn.setCellFactory((TreeTableColumn<Person, Number> _) -> {
            TreeTableCell<Person, Number> cell = new TreeTableCell<>() {

                @Override
                public void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    if (item != null && item.intValue() != -1) {
                        setText(item.toString());
                    } else {
                        setText("");
                    }
                }

            };
            cell.getStyleClass().add("age-cell");
            return cell;
        });

with the (again simpler) style sheet
.tree-table-row-cell .name-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: orange;
}
.tree-table-row-cell .age-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
}
.tree-table-row-cell:selected .tree-table-cell {
    -fx-text-fill: inherit;
}


Both solutions you suggested work correctly. The question is, imagine a software in which the user has to change the color of the cells according to their choice, using the style sheet, they have to think of some parser to keep changing this sheet, and this seems impractical compared to a properties file or JSON. For fixed things, CSS is practical, for variable things, if there was a way to include all the instructions with the CSS selectors, it would be fantastic.

@tretonis "they have to think of some parser to keep changing this sheet". No, you can just use looked-up colors. But this is completely different to anything you asked in the question.
